# 3 blogs on one site with the same header menu?

Tags: multisite, menus, headers

Person X has default SITE with an integral blog. Person X also has SITE 2 with Blog 2 and also SITE 3 with Blog 3.

Is it possible to have on the DEFAULT SITE HEADER MENU something like this:

```
HOME BLOG1 BLOG2 BLOG3 CONTACTUS
```

BLOG1 is a integral blog of that DEFAULT SITE. Blog 2 tab would link to the blog 2 of the site 2. Blog 3 tab would link to the site 3 with blog 3. The point is when user clicks at the BLOG2 and BLOG3 tabs to get content from these blogs, the HEADERMENU of default site always stays on the top and it is always the same.

Is that possible? (categories of a single blog as a solution excluded).

Possible solution is to mimic BLOG 2 and BLOG 3 with exactly the same header (with linked tabs) that could give a simulation of the same page all the way, but that would be cheating and it is hard to update all these blogs-sites like that (especially if new tab appears in the future). Is there any other more logical-better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The first, and likely best, solution is to use a WordPress network where BLOG 1 resides at `example.com`.

BLOG 2 is a totally separate blog, but within the context of the network and lives at a subdirectory like `example.com/blog2`. And so on...

The second solution is to use a plugin that pulls in feeds from external blogs and saves them to BLOG 1's database.

The third solution is to use iframes to include BLOG 2 on a separate page on BLOG 1.

Comment: Thanks Developdaly. Yes I am going with WordPress network and I will create blog 2 on the subdirectory. But the problem is how can EXAMPLE.COM on his TAB called "BLOG 2", show actuall contest from that subdirectory blog (on the default index tab "BLOG 2" of example.com. That is my problem. How to move on, do you have any suggestions? Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: IF the first option isn't good enough, the second two do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually a fourth idea (if you absolutely don't want to use categories) is to create 2 new post types. `post`, `post_2`, `post_3` and each can be managed through a single blog with their own archives on one site. I don't suggest this, but it's doable.

Comment: Thanks developdaly. After considering all options, I think that I have to admit that I crossed the same path like others before me. I will probably go with categories after all. I tried also iframe option but it not estetic resolution, alhough it is good to know the possibilities. I could maybe try 4th option so we will see. But will probably go with the categories after all. Thanks for all of your efforts, this will be good archive for all the others after me that will stumble on the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that these sites already exist. What might be best and possibly the simplest solution would be to create a plugin that adds an additional nav bar to the top of every site with a shared navigation. That way you can maintain the logic and linking in one place.

If you are working within a multisite network you will still need to do some custom coding. With that said the database tables for each blog on the network reside in the same database. So knowing the ID of the respective blogs can let you query posts and content from the blogs on the network.

Answer (score -1):

Your question begs another question - do I need separate websites?  Building a WP multisite can introduce some huge headaches (stability, conflicts, confusion, etc) into your life, and I'd almost always discourage it.  If you are concerned about SEO, there is a good video by Matt Cutts, of Google, on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MswMYk05tk

Here's a better solution:
Check out the widget logic plugin in the WordPress plugins directory.  It gives you the tools to turn widgets on and off on a per-section basis so that you get the feel of a different site for each blog.  You could also use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in your theme to further modify the look on a per-blog basis.

Comment: Can you you explain how this applies to the specific question asked? "Is it possible to have on the DEFAULT SITE HEADER MENU something like...?"

Answer (score -1):

Stumbeld upon this today, think i have some advice for anyone sees this: 
This can be easily resolved in some ways:

1. using [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types): the user should register 2 more post types (for example - reviews, stories...) and the each button will list the post types in an archive template.
2. using [Categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates): using The posts but splitting them to different categories. each button will show different posts from the same category in an archive template.

Solutions like multisite's will only make things complicated and keep you away from your goal.

I hope it helped